# How to generate Vcard of the selected contact from the default Contacts application in ios

Tags: ios

Hello i am trying to build an app in ios which will pick a contact from the phone book and it will generate a vcard for that particular contact.How can i do that?please give me some solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://altoshstock.blogspot.in/2010/11/iphone-os-generate-vcard.html)

May this solve your purpose.